# Not work addClass

Tags: jquery

i use Datatables (jQuery plugin) and all rows have many buttons where doing somethink work (send to server request - edit, delete and etc).

I want then after click on one of this bottons, added class name 'disabled' and after doing work this class removed.

But class 'disabled' not added. **But, if i delete `$(this).removeClass('disabled');`, button will be with this class!**  Why? Or it my local problems?

I have this HTML

```
<a id='change-color' class='btn btn-danger'>Change Color</a>
```

And this JS code

```
$(document).on('click', '#change-color', function(){
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    var _this = this; // hmm.. can i do it without this spick?..

    $.get('/', function(text){
        if($(_this).hasClass('btn-danger')){
            $(_this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
        } else {
            $(_this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
        }
    });
    $(this).removeClass('disabled');
});
```

### [LIVE ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gFbNm/2/)

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous. You are sending a GET request and then your code is immediately going to the next statement and removing the class. Move the `removeClass` portion potion your callback.

Comment: This note is besides your question, but just for slightly better performance do `var $this = $(this)` so inside your callbacks you don't have to do `$(_this)` each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the class immediately after you add it; well before the asynchronous callback executes. Remove the class inside the callback instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#change-color', function(){
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    var _this = this; // hmm.. can i do it wihout this stafff?..

    $.get('/', function(text){
        if($(_this).hasClass('btn-danger')){
            $(_this).removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
        } else {
            $(_this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
        }
        // Removes the class AFTER the Ajax request completes
        $(this).removeClass('disabled'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Why i cant do it after `$.get()`?

Comment: @AlexKiselev Because $.get() is operating asynchronously, which means statements after it are run without waiting for it to complete.